# MacBookPro freezes in lock screen when waking up after sleep in Sierra

Tags: sleep-wake, macos, performance, unlock

After updating my MacBookPro to macOS Sierra, the display sometimes freezes in the *lock screen*, when waking up from sleep. I have to wait for a few seconds before the Mac allows me to insert my password and unlock it.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Comment: Mine actually crashes, forcing the computer to reboot. Did you take it to a store?

Comment: No, I was wondering if there were a more immediate solution for fixing this issue.